# How to implement socketchannel using socketcluster

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am using socketcluster API. I am planning to implement enter room in to conference and leaving conference concept. Can you help for good tutorial or How can i start implementing?

Thanks,
kav

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pub/sub channels. Check out http://socketcluster.io/#!/docs/full-stack - It should give you the basic info about how to get started.